# Delay using timer on raspberry pi

Tags: timer, raspberry-pi

I need to create a accurate delay (around 100us) inside a thread function. I tried using the nanosleep function but it was no accurate enough. I read some post about how to read the hardware 1MHz timer, so on my function in order to create a 100us delay y tried something like this:

```
prev = *timer;    
do {
    t = *timer;
} while ((t - prev) < 100);
```

However, the program seems to stay inside the loop. But if I insert a small nano sleep inside the loop it works (but loosing precision):

```
sleeper.tv_sec  = 0;
sleeper.tv_nsec = (long)(1);
prev = *timer;
do {
    nanosleep (&sleeper, &dummy);
    t = *timer;
} while ((t - prev) < 500);
```

I tried the first version in a stand along program and it works, but in my main program, where this is inside a thread it does not.

Does anyone know what the first version (without a small nanosleep) does not work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say but Raspberry Pi's OS is not a "real-time OS". In another words, you won't get consistent 100us precision in a user space program due to inherent OS scheduling limitations. If you need that kind of precision, you should use an embedded controller like an Arduino.